# Prove that $\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta=1$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I try to find the question but I didn't

How do you do it? I'm really stuck on this proof. Can someone please explain?

Comment: What definition of cos and sin are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Try geometrically: draw a unitary circle and an angle $\alpha$. Then $\sin\alpha$ and $\cos\alpha$ and the radius will form exactly a right angled triangle, and the formula you're searching for will be exactly the Pitagora Theorem.

Comment: Pythagorean* theorem?

Comment: Yes. But I'm Italian and I like to call Greek men with the names I've always used (unless it gives confusion).

Comment: I understand. But I'm afraid very different names, such as that one, does provide confusion.